# Read in yes/no boolean from terminal and produce an if else with inputted value

Tags: java

I asked a user if they would like to play a game..

```
    System.out.println("Would you like to play"); 
     read in yes or no value 
        if yes (display text) 
        else (display other text)
```

I have used the scanner previously in the program, I just need it to use it again. Do I need to declare another new one with new variables?

Comment: The answer is no. But why not just try and see what happens?

Answer (score 2):

you could do something like:

```
    String yesOrNo = System.in.readLine();
    String textToDisplay = (yesOrNo.equals("Yes")) ? "text to display when yesOrNo equals yes" : "text to display when YesOrNo equals no";
```

Comment: Forgot to use `.equals()` for comparing strings! Fixed now!

Answer (score 2):

Use this method:

```
scanner.nextBoolean()
```

So then it'd be:

```
System.out.println("Would you like to play?");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

if(scanner.nextBoolean()==true) {
    System.out.println("This will be fun");
} else {
    System.out.println("Maybe next time");
}
```

---

Edit

---

```
System.out.println("Would you like to play?");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String val = scanner.next();
if(val.equalsIgnoreCase("y")||val.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
    System.out.println("This will be fun");
} else if(val.equalsIgnoreCase("n")||val.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
    System.out.println("Maybe next time");
} else { 
System.out.println("Invalid character");
```

Comment: It doesnt appear to be accepting anything that I input from the command line. thus, not displaying the if else statements.

Comment: Okay, then there are a few things to do. Stay with me, this might get ugly.. I'm revising my answer above.

Comment: Ok so, It works for 'y' only, if i type in 'yes, 'n' or 'no' the program does not end, i have to crash it myself, its peculiar

Comment: @dragon66 how can I over come this problem?

Comment: @Javaer: save the scanner.next() to a variable. Then test it against the string you are expecting: like "yes","y" etc.

Comment: @dragon66 How would I go about that ? Chad M: yes please

Comment: To keep it clean, I will be posting another answer, not editing this one.

Comment: I only need to ask the user if they would like to play, then produce a text output if they yes or no.

Answer (score 1):

To make it simple, here is something for you to play with:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Would you like to play: 'y' or 'yes' to accept; 'n' or 'no' to reject; 'q' to quit:");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);    
    String token = "";

    while(scanner.hasNextLine())
    {
       token = scanner.nextLine().trim();

       if(token.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) System.exit(0);

       if(token.equalsIgnoreCase("y")||token.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) 
       {
           System.out.println("Thanks for your interest!");
           System.exit(0);
       }
       else if (token.equalsIgnoreCase("n")||token.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
       {
           System.out.println("That's a pity!");
           System.exit(0);
       }
       else
       {
           System.out.println("Oops, not a valid input!");
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon this question and the answer of Chad M is correct, but - like some commenters mentioned above - has some bugs in it. So here is my implementation without the bugs (it was just a question of saving the user input into a string variable):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput = scanner.next();

if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
    // y or yes
} else {
    // other character
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on a recommendation of dragon66, I'm implementing a String comparison of predefined inputs compared to user input.

```
System.out.println("Would you like to play? Or press Q to exit"):
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String affirmative = "yes";
    String affirmative2 = "y";
    String negative = "no";
    String negative2 = "n";
    String quit = "q";

if(scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase(affirmative)||scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase(affirmative2)) {
    System.out.println("This will be fun");
} else if(scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase(negative)||scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase(negative2)) {
    System.out.println("Maybe next time");
} else if(scanner.next().equalsIgnoreCase(quit)){ 
    System.out.println("Good bye");
    System.exit();
} else {
System.out.println("Invalid character");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatley Im having similar problems as before. also to compile the code i had to change the system.exit(); to system.exit(1); otherwise i would have errors.

Comment: Wouldn't that over complicate things for this small program? From my understanding, then you would be comparing to String objects, which would then need to implement Comparable.

Comment: @Javaer the system.exit method needs a status. Status `0` means normal termination of the JVM, without errors. Any other status code indicates problems. But you cannot call the method without arguments, so just use `System.exit(0);`.