# Having problem in this boolean thing of java

Tags: java, boolean, boolean-operations

> A student will not be allowed to sit in exam if his/her attendence is less than 75%.Take following input from user:
>
> - Number of classes held
> - Number of classes attended
>
> and print percentage of class attended is student is allowed to sit in exam or not.
>
> Modify the above question to allow student to sit if he/she has medical cause. Ask user if he/she has medical cause or not ( 'Y' or 'N' ) and print accordingly.

So I am having a trouble in this question at medical part. Can someone tell me how to make this code more good. here is my code.

```
package A;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Practice5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // A student will not be allowed to sit in exam if his/her attendence is less than 75%
        
        Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter number of class attendend");
        float Ca = S.nextFloat();
        
        System.out.println("Enter number of class held");
        float Ch = S.nextFloat();
        
        System.out.println("Did student have any medical cause \"true or false?\"");
        boolean medical = S.nextBoolean();
        
        if(Ca/Ch*100 >75 ) {
                System.out.println("You are allowed to sit in exam with "+Ca/Ch*100 +" Percentage of attendence");
        }
        
        if (medical) {
            System.out.println("You are allowed to sit in exam with "+Ca/Ch*100 +" Percentage of attendence");
        }
        
        else {
            System.out.println("You are not allowed to sit in exam with "+ Ca/Ch*100 + " Percentage of attendance");
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read in yes/no boolean from terminal and produce an if else with inputted value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386011/read-in-yes-no-boolean-from-terminal-and-produce-an-if-else-with-inputted-value)

Comment: You just need an `else` before the second `if`. This doesn't have much to do with `boolean`s.

Answer (score 2):

Combine the conditions for which the student is allowed to attend the class. In this question, the conditions are medical == true or the % of class attended should be greater than 75. Please see the below code for reference

```
package A;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Practice5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // A student will not be allowed to sit in exam if his/her attendence is less than 75%
        
        Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter number of class attendend");
        float Ca = S.nextFloat();
        
        System.out.println("Enter number of class held");
        float Ch = S.nextFloat();
        
        System.out.println("Did student have any medical cause \"true or false?\"");
        boolean medical = S.nextBoolean();

        if (medical || (Ca/Ch*100 >75)) {
            System.out.println("You are allowed to sit in exam with "+Ca/Ch*100 +" Percentage of attendence");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You are not allowed to sit in exam with "+ Ca/Ch*100 + " Percentage of attendance");
        }
        
    }

}
```